# how to display value in dropdown list depending on another dropdownlist using jsp?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, database-connection

I'm tying to bind the value to dropdownlist i.e named as `subtype` which is depending on another dropdownlist i.e named as `type`. Please tell me how I can do that.. I have given I following code which implement for binding the dropdownlist depending on another dropdownlist.

```
  `<table>
  <tr>
  <td>
 <label id="type">Chosen category : </label>
 </td>
 <td>
 <% String getType=request.getParameter("id");
 out.println("<h4>"+getType+"  <a href='post free ads.jsp'>Change the
 category</a>   </h4>");
 %>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>
 <label id="typeselect">Select type : </label>
 </td>
 <td>
 <select name="type">  
     <option value="none">Select</option>  
  <%
  Connection conn = NewClass.getOracleConnection();
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select distinct company from admin.all_stuff
   where stuff_type='"+getType+"' ");
  while(rs.next()){
      %>
      <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>
       <%
  }
 %>
  </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> <label id="subtypeselect">Select Subtype : </label></td>
 <td>
     <select name="subtype">  
  <option value="none">Select</option>  
     <%
  try
  { %>
 <% String typeselected = request.getParameter("type");
  Statement stmtmt = conn.createStatement();  
  ResultSet rse = stmtmt.executeQuery("Select model_no from admin.all_stuff
  where stuff_type='"+getType+"' and company='"+typeselected+"' ");
  while(rse.next()){
      %>
      <option value="<%=rse.getString(1)%>"><%=rse.getString(1)%></option> 
      <%
  }
  %>
  <% }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
  %>
  }
    </select> 
     
 </td>
  </tr>
    </table>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need AJAX for this to get it work.

Your jsp is compiled into a servlet and then delivered to your client. After that no more changes are possible.

You have to handle an `onChange` event on the first drop down box in HTML and then post an AJAX request to your server to send back the content for the second drop down box.

Comment: sry but i have never tried the ajax programming can u plzz tell me how to do that..with simple example

Comment: Read tutorials on AJAX e.g. Dojo and DWR. If you don't have any experience with JavaScript also ask someone for help on this part.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to start with AJAX is to get some library for example jQuery

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

This code allow us to download from HTML page some content from URL 'ajax/test.html'.
Second argument is callback function. Variable data has content of page 'ajax/test.html'

More: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/